# How to store values from a form to local storage in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, html

I have some code for adding the values from a form to the local storage,
but when I tried the code, it is not running. I would like to store the form data in local storage by clicking the button. I am adding my sample code below:

```js
App.controller('KeyController', function($scope,$localStorage) { 
  /*$scope.info = 'Welcome to Test';*/
  /*console.log(" Key controller is working ");*/
  
 

  $scope.api_url;
  $scope.api_token;    

    $scope.submit=function(){ 
    localStorage.setItem('api_url','--------');
    localStorage.setItem('api_token','--------');

    console.log(api_url);
    console.log(api_token)
   }


 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">


  <form role = "form" id="uriForm" name="authfrom">

    <div class = "form-group">
       <label for = "url">Enter the url to authenticate:</label>
       <input type = "url" class = "form-control"  placeholder = "Enter the URL" ng-model="api_url" required="required">
    </div>
    
     <div class = "form-group">
       <label for = "Key">Enter the key here:</label>
       <textarea class = "form-control" rows="5"  placeholder = "Enter the Key" ng-model="api_token" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>
    
    <button class = "btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()">Explore!!</button>
    <p class="warning">{{failed}}</p>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You haven't add your app.js file in html.
2. You didn't add your `ng-app` and `ng-controller` in html.
3. You were adding $localStorage in function which is not necessary.
4. You were using wrong syntax for `localStorage.setItem()` 
   Now I've edited your code and made this.

Here is index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="KeyController">
<div class="container">
<form>
       <div class = "form-group">
          <label for = "url">Enter the url to authenticate:</label>
          <input type = "text" class = "form-control"  placeholder = "Enter the URL" ng-model="api_url" required="required">
       </div>

        <div class = "form-group">
          <label for = "Key">Enter the key here:</label>
          <textarea class = "form-control" rows="5"  placeholder = "Enter the Key" ng-model="api_token" required="required"></textarea>
       </div>

       <button class = "btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()">Explore!!</button>
       <p class="warning">{{failed}}</p>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is your app.js file:

```
angular.module('app', [])
 .controller('KeyController', function($scope) { 
  $scope.api_url;
  $scope.api_token;
    $scope.submit=function(){   
        localStorage.setItem('api_url', JSON.stringify($scope.api_url));
        localStorage.setItem('api_token', JSON.stringify($scope.api_token));

        console.log($scope.api_url);
        console.log($scope.api_token)
    }
  });
```

You can copy paste this and check your self. First replace the reference of `angular.min.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the below code which has been corrected to bootstrap the angular module and set controller using `ng-app` and `ng-controller`.

Code snippets posted on stackoverflow cannot access `localstorage` for the reason mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/why-are-we-disallowed-to-use-html5-local-storage-on-code-snippets). So you'll need to run this code on your local development environment.

```js
angular
  .module('MyApp', []);

angular
  .module('MyApp')
  .controller('KeyController', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
      /*$scope.info = 'Welcome to Test';*/
      /*console.log(" Key controller is working ");*/
      $scope.api_url;
      $scope.api_token;
      $scope.savedApiUrl = '';
      $scope.savedApiToken = '';

      $scope.submit = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('api_url', $scope.api_url);
        localStorage.setItem('api_token', $scope.api_token);

        var savedApiUrl = localStorage.getItem('api_url');
        var savedApiToken = localStorage.getItem('api_token');
        $scope.savedApiUrl = savedApiUrl;
        $scope.savedApiToken = savedApiToken;
        console.log($scope.savedApiUrl);
        console.log($scope.savedApiToken)
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="KeyController">

  <form role="form" id="uriForm" name="authfrom">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="url">Enter the url to authenticate:</label>
      <input type="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the URL" ng-model="api_url" required="required">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Key">Enter the key here:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter the Key" ng-model="api_token" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()">Explore!!</button>
    <p class="warning">{{failed}}</p>
  </form>

  <p>Saved values from local storage</p>
  <p>API URL: {{savedApiUrl}}</p>
  <p>API Token: {{savedApiToken}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: :-Thanks for you help its working fine,..wish u all the success